# Symmetric domain of a double integral

Tags: calculus, multiple-integral

Suppose that I want to evaluate the following double integral :
$$\iint_D(2y-1)$$
where D is a triangle with vertices $(0,1),(1,0),(-1,0)$.

I know the method of constructing the triangle and solving it. My question is since the domain is symmetric can I integrate it over one half and multiply it by 2? I tried it with this problem and the answer was same but I am not sure whether it is mathematically correct?
Thank You.

Comment: Yes, because $D$ is symmetric about the $y-$ axis and $2y-1$ **does not depend on $x$**.

Comment: @geetha290krm ok so will it apply for every case? Also as a counter example, when integrating in 1D, why can't we do the same with cosx while integrating it between -pi/2 and pi/2 because here also domain is symmetric about origin?

Comment: What makes you think you can't do it with $\cos x$? It's an even function, and the interval is symmetric, so indeed we have $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos x \, dx = 2 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos x \, dx$.

Comment: Anyway, it's important to note that you can't just look at the domain; the **integrand** also needs to have the corresponding symmetry.

Comment: @HansLundmark ok so basically both domain and integrand should be symmetric then it can be done and in my case since the integrand doesn't depend on x it is symmetric?

Comment: @Sj2704: Exactly.